# Space between background color of text on each line?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have set the background color of the Text widget, but if there are multiple line then the color is connected between lines. I want color to have space between each line of the text.

[image: Text with background color but with space between each line]

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue with tricky way!
with underline of font, it make a gap.

```
Container(
   color: Colors.red,
   child: Text("Ask Me Anything. but this text will wrap because it's long",
     style: TextStyle(
     fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
     fontSize: 32,
     height: 1.8,
     color: Colors.transparent, // => 4. remove original text
     backgroundColor: Colors.black,
     decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
     decorationColor: Colors.red, // => 1. make a underline with same color with background. in this case, red.
     decorationThickness: 6, // 2. modify a underline thickness by font "height" so it cover gap between lines.
     shadows: [Shadow(color: Colors.white, offset: Offset(0, -15))] // => 3. make a shadow for making duplicated text on upper side 
 )),
```

This solution still got problem.
The Space between lines can not modify. It's only depend on height for this code.

but you can got the gap anyway.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
strutStyle: StrutStyle(height: 2,forceStrutHeight: true),
```

inside text widget

Answer (score -1):

you to have spaces within lines, you can separate each text to its own widget and add them to a column where you can set a space between theme with sizedBox :

```
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Ask me"),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text("Anything"),
          ],
        ),
```

there are also more solutions, you can use `RichText` widget :

```
    Text.rich(TextSpan(children: [
          TextSpan(text: "Ask me"),
          TextSpan("\n"),
          TextSpan(text: "Anything"),
        ])),
```

Comment: This is not a possible solution. The Text is dynamic and will be inputted by the user.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are using paint() as text background.

If so you can try text line height, it might fix your issue.

Comment: I am using backgorundColor property on the TextStyle Object. Changing the line does nothing.